# Split list of delimited lines to hash

Tags: perl

The following produces what i want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.020;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

sub command {
    <DATA>
    #in the reality instead of the DATA I have
    #qx(some weird shell command what produces output like in the DATA);

}
my @lines = grep { !/^\s*$/ } command();
chomp @lines;

my $data;

#how to write the following nicer - more compact, elegant, etc.. ;)
for my $line (@lines) {
    my @arr = split /:/, $line;
    $data->{$arr[0]}->{text} = $arr[1];
    $data->{$arr[0]}->{par} = $arr[2];
    $data->{$arr[0]}->{val} = $arr[3];
}
say Dumper $data;

__DATA__
line1:some text1:par1:val1
line2:some text2:par2:val2

line3:some text3:par3:val3
```

Wondering how to write the loop in more *perlish* form. ;)

Comment: @Biffen done. The `use 5.020` included it, with a couple of `use feature`...

Comment: I (foolishly) just looked for `use strict;`. Mea culpa.

Comment: `say` was introduced before 5.20. `use feature 'say'` works in any perl version that supports `say`. Moreover, `Dumper` adds the final newline, so no `say` is needed.

Comment: Open the reading pipe to external proc instead of `qx` and use `.. while <$pipe>`

Comment: @chroba - ok. simply, the say is shorter. I hope, this hasn't effect to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign to a hash slice:

```
for my $line (@lines) {
    my ($id, @arr) = split /:/, $line;
    @{ $data->{$id} }{qw{ text par val }} = @arr;
}
```

Also, use the following instead of `qx`, so you don't need to store all the lines in an array:

```
open my $PIPE, '-|', 'command' or die $!;
while (<$PIPE>) {
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx - exactly for what i'm looking. :) :) accepting in 30 secs. ;)

Comment: I want store the output - and the `qx` works for me. Is here any problem with using `qx`?

Comment: @kobame: If the output is large or coming slowly, it might be a problem. Also, you have to handle all the quoting, while `open` can take a list like `system` does.